# Zend Framework: how to get message instead of Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

For example, we have IndexController. Application.ini - all log errors are true:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

I tried to set up `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`

At last in indexAction I'm writing:

```
Zend_Auth::hasIdentity();
```

After this one I have got Internal Server Error.

This is clear, because we cannot run `hasIdentity()` as static. 
I can get a var_dump in this function but when I run `$this->getStorage()` init I have got Internal Server Error.

So I would like to get some error message with description. No like Internal Server Error.

If I doing smth like this in a simple php application (not Zend Framework) - I have got a full error description without Internal Server Error.

So how to get description instead of Internal Server Error there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you wrote it seems that your APPLICATION_ENV is not set to *development*. You can set APPLICATION_ENV to development in your public/.htaccess by adding the following line  `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development` into your *.htaccess*.

Comment: Thanks. Seems it works. But I see Internal Server Error in the end of the page anyway. 
How to hide this message? I know how to hide it in standart error template - set 'die' in the end of the template. Seems it is not a good idea.

Comment: @Anthony. Glad to help, but why do you want to hide the errors? I tough that you wanted to see more details, no to hide them. You can have a look at errorController.php or error.phtml, and try to customize them to show what you want. Anyway, if you think my answer is acceptable, I would be happy if you could accept it.

Comment: I see error description in the body of the page. That is right.
But after teg </html> I see Internal Server Error. This is not good. I don't know how to hide Internal Server Error in the correct way.

Comment: @Anthony. So it seems that the source of the error is not that related to your application. Have a look at apache logs. Maybe there you will find what causes this server error.

Comment: I checked this in the first place.
Unfortunately, there are not any errors of late:(
I'm using Zend Server